# Panel Control for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for a Panel UI option comparable to the AJAX Update Panel or ASP.NET Panel Server controls for MVC but so far I am not getting much results.

I am not interested so much in the AJAX Panels capability to control full page postbacks since that's not an issue in the MVC world, but toward of the ability to contain other objects within another container on the page with scrollbars.

I have used the div tags in effort to simulate this and its a hack at best because I am rendering a object tree structure and sometimes the scrollbars don't seem to detect the need to be present using overflow: scroll; and setting it to always be present does not neccessarily mean that the scrollbars will be functional when needed.

Can anyone provide some direction to a web control that would give this functionality for MVC? Preferrably free. :-) I have found nothing in the Telerik suite of controls for MVC for this.